# jQuery Shimmer Button Effect

Tags: jquery, button, effect

Is there a way to create a shimmer effect on an HTML element, using jQuery, simulating a moving lightsource? I see this on Flash components, but haven't seen one with jQuery yet. Want to avoid having to make shimmering GIFs if I can.

**EDIT1**: I imagine I'll have to capture the hover event and then use animate to stack a white fuzzy diagonal image on top of an IMG or DIV tag's boundaries, moving it from left to right once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just made an example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/pZm2m/

is this similar to what you are looking for ?

It does what you mention .. animate a diagonal semi transparent image.

I used the *Background-Position-Animation* plugin found at http://plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect

Comment: BTW, that's the first time I ever saw a BinHex'd and URL-Encoded image loaded in CSS. I had not known that was possible. Simply astounding, and it works in IE too. (Tested in IE8 and the latest FF.) Plus, if one's browser doesn't support it, it doesn't error our and degrades nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tutorial with a jQuery shimmer effect (demo link at the bottom of the post):

http://www.eu-live.com/?p=164

Comment: Unfortunately that version of the effect only highlights the white borders and doesn't shine a light source across the apple itself. I'm looking for something that shines a light source across the apple, too.

Comment: @Volomike, you can use similar code but apply transparency to the image and stack it on top.  Shinning a light source across the apple however would be quite a feet.  you would need a 3D rendering engine for that.

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this one (not my code) and it looks quite workable:

http://tedtoy.github.io/ShimmerJS/

Answer (score 0):

Another opportunity is this one:

http://www.nealgrosskopf.com/tech/thread.php?pid=79

Uses CSS3 and works on recent (2011+) Mozilla, Opera, Chrome, Safari, and perhaps IE eventually.